# LINQ with Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, lambda

How can I convert the `LINQ` query below using `LAMBDA Expressions` ?

```
    var select = from si in db.San_Imovel
                 join sic in db.San_Imovel_caracteristica
                 on si.Imovel_Id equals Convert.ToInt64(sic.Imovel_Id)
                 join sf in db.San_Filial
                 on si.Credenciada_Id equals sf.Credenciada_Id
                 where si.Credenciada_Id == credenciada_Id
                 && (si.GrupoImovel_Id.ToString().Contains("1") || si.GrupoImovel_Id.ToString().Contains("2"))
                 && (si.Status_Id.ToString().Contains("1") || si.Status_Id.ToString().Contains("12"))
                 && si.NomeArquivo != null
                 && (si.Imovel_Id.ToString().Contains(""))
                 select new
                 {
                     si.Celula_Id,
                     si.Credenciada_Id,
                     si.Imovel_Id,
                     si.NomeArquivo,
                     si.TipoDsc1,
                     si.BairroDsc1,
                     si.AreaRealPrivativa,
                     sic.VagasGaragem,
                     si.ValorImovel,
                     si.ValorCondominio,
                     si.ValorIPTU,
                     si.Lat2,
                     si.Lon2,
                     sf.ApelidoCredenciada,
                     sf.ddd,
                     sf.TelefoneVenda,
                     sf.TelefoneLocacao,
                     sf.Email,
                     si.Bairro1,
                     si.NomeCidade,
                     si.Transacao_ID
                 };
```

Comment: Why would you want to? It's going to end up being much harder to read, after two joins.

Comment: This is because I need to do a `Dynamic LINQ` like in Scot Gu's blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = 
   db.San_Imovel
     .Join(db.San_Imovel_caracteristica,
           si => Imovel_Id,
           sic => Convert.ToInt64(sic.Imovel_Id),
           (si, sic) => new { si, sic })
     .Join(db.San_Filial,
           x => x.si.Credenciada_Id,
           sf => sf.Credenciada_Id,
           (x, sf) => new { x.si, x.sic, sf })
     .Where(x => x.si.Credenciada_Id == credenciada_Id &&
                 (x.si.GrupoImovel_Id.ToString().Contains("1") || 
                  x.si.GrupoImovel_Id.ToString().Contains("2")) &&
                 (x.si.Status_Id.ToString().Contains("1") || 
                  x.si.Status_Id.ToString().Contains("12")) &&
                  x.si.NomeArquivo != null &&
                 (x.si.Imovel_Id.ToString().Contains(""))
     .Select(x => new {
                     x.si.Celula_Id,
                     x.si.Credenciada_Id,
                     x.si.Imovel_Id,
                     x.si.NomeArquivo,
                     x.si.TipoDsc1,
                     x.si.BairroDsc1,
                     x.si.AreaRealPrivativa,
                     x.sic.VagasGaragem,
                     x.si.ValorImovel,
                     x.si.ValorCondominio,
                     x.si.ValorIPTU,
                     x.si.Lat2,
                     x.si.Lon2,
                     x.sf.ApelidoCredenciada,
                     x.sf.ddd,
                     x.sf.TelefoneVenda,
                     x.sf.TelefoneLocacao,
                     x.sf.Email,
                     x.si.Bairro1,
                     x.si.NomeCidade,
                     x.si.Transacao_ID
                 });
```

*BTW* you don't need to convert whole query to method syntax. You can convert only filtering `where` part.